# Big performance loss when using IN(subquery). Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I am using SQL Server 2005 and I have noticed something strange when I want to filter some results when using a subquery within an IN clause.  For instance, this is my current query and it runs in 70 seconds on average:

```
select Phone, ZipCode, sum(Calls) as Calls, sum(Sales) as Sales
from Archive 
where CustomerID = 20
and ReportDate = '2/3/2011'
and Phone in (
    select Phone
    from PlanDetails 
    where Phone is not null
    and Length is not null
    and PlannedImp > 0
    and CustomerID = 20
    and (StatusID <> 2 and StatusID <> 7)
    and SubcategoryID = 88
)
group by Phone, ZipCode
```

However, if I break them down into 2 separate queries, they take under 1 second each to run.

```
select Phone
from PlanDetails 
where Phone is not null
and Length is not null
and PlannedImp > 0
and CustomerID = 20
and (StatusID <> 2 and StatusID <> 7)
and SubcategoryID = 88
```

and

```
select Phone, ZipCode, sum(Calls) as Calls, sum(Sales) as Sales
from Archive 
where CustomerID = 20
and ReportDate = '2/3/2011'
group by Phone, ZipCode
```

Finally, if I do this it returns the same results as the first query, but in about 2-3 seconds:

```
select Phone
into #tempTable
from PlanDetails
where Phone is not null
and Length is not null
and PlannedImp > 0
and CustomerID = 20
and (StatusID <> 2 and StatusID <> 7)
and SubcategoryID = 88

select Phone, ZipCode, sum(Calls) as Calls, sum(Sales) as Sales
from Archive 
where CustomerID = 20
and ReportDate = '2/3/2011'
and Phone in (
    select Phone
    from #tempTable
)
group by Phone, ZipCode
```

For the past few weeks I have been noticing that not just this query is slow, but any query using a (somewhat complicated) subquery inside of an IN clause just ruins the performance. What is the reason for that?

The only indexes that are available for either of these queries to use is a nonclustered index on CustomerID for both tables.  I looked at the execution plans of both the slow query and the fast ones, and saw that the nonclustered index seek on the Archive table is what takes the highest percentage of cost by far (80-90%). However, the only difference is that that step in the slow query has a CPU cost of 7.1 while the fast ones have a CPU cost of 1.7.

Comment: When this kind of stuff happends (wrong query plan) running sp_updatestats sometimes solves the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends upon the database system, the version, the settings, etc. but generally what ends up happening is the database fails (or refuses) to cache that inner query, so it is being executed **every single iteration** of the outer query. You are changing your problem from a O(n) efficiency class to O(n^2).

Comment: This is exactly what was happening.  After viewing the execution plan as a data table instead of the graphical plan, I noticed that the subquery method was showing MUCH more executes (~326000) vs an inner join (~14244)

Answer (score 2):

Quote [IN vs. JOIN vs. EXISTS](http://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/):

> We see now that contrary to the popular opinion, IN / EXISTS queries are not less efficient than a JOIN query in SQL Server.
>
> In fact, JOIN queries are less efficient on non-indexed tables, since Semi Join methods allow aggregation and matching against a single hash table, while a JOIN needs to do these two operations in two steps.

Beyond that, indexing and how current table statistics are plays a large role in how the optimizer decides to execute a query.

Answer (score 2):

What if you rewrite the query with a join?

```
select a.Phone, a.ZipCode, sum(a.Calls) as Calls, sum(a.Sales) as Sales
from Archive a
    inner join PlanDetails pd
        on a.CustomerID = pd.CustomerID
            and a.Phone = pd.Phone
where a.CustomerID = 20
    and a.ReportDate = '2/3/2011'
    and pd.Length is not null
    and pd.PlannedImp > 0
    and (pd.StatusID <> 2 and pd.StatusID <> 7)
    and pd.SubcategoryID = 88
group by a.Phone, a.ZipCode
```

Comment: This does work quickly (<2 seconds), but I'm really trying to figure out why the IN(subquery) is messing everything up so I will know when to avoid those types of queries in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I'd propose 2 solutions :
1. Try to rewrite your query using `EXISTS` instead of `IN`. It might help if you use the older SQL Server versions (If my memory serves me well, prior to SQL Server 2005 `EXITST` and `IN` generated different execution plans).
2. Try to use `INNER JOIN` (you can also use CTE):

```
select Phone, ZipCode, sum(Calls) as Calls, sum(Sales) as Sales
from Archive 
INNER JOIN 
(
  select DISTINCT Phone // DISTINCT to avoid duplicates
  from PlanDetails 
  where Phone is not null
  and Length is not null
  and PlannedImp > 0
  and CustomerID = 20
  and (StatusID <> 2 and StatusID <> 7)
  and SubcategoryID = 88
)XX ON (XX.Phone = Archive.Phone)  
where CustomerID = 20 and ReportDate = '2/3/2011'    
group by Phone, ZipCode
```

Personally, I'd expect the second approach to give you much better results.

Comment: Strangely enough, this takes roughly the same amount of time as the first query.  I think its the fact of having that select from PlanDetails within the subquery that is messing everything up.

Comment: @Jason how is the EXISTS query performing?