# Access 2007: Subqueries causing massive performance loss

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am building a query to search for records matching any number of fields in a table with 15+ columns. (All fields for which an input is given must match.)

However, the original table was badly designed, in some cases having upwards of ten fields for the same thing. (With names such as Street_11.) I have separated the data into multiple tables such that `Street_2` through `Street_12` are now all labeled under `Street_2` in a separate table, containing only that column and `fileID`, which is taken from the main table's primary key. (There is no formal relation between the two, though `fileID` in the secondary table serves as a foreign key.)

Prior to the normalization efforts, the search form was using [this query](http://pastebin.com/A4WFUZKX). While not optimal, it was at least functional. I have since removed the segments searching the `Street_X` and `Block_X` fields, replacing them with subqueries:

```
WHERE 
(
    [Map index].fileID IN 
    (
    SELECT fileID FROM [fileID-Street] 
    WHERE [fileID-Street].Street_2 LIKE "*" & [Forms]![DW_Form]![Street] & "*"
    ) 
  OR 
    ([Forms]![DW_Form]![Street] Is Null)
)
AND 
(
    [Map index].fileID IN 
    (
    SELECT fileID FROM [fileID-blockLot] 
    WHERE [fileID-blockLot].Block LIKE "*" & [Forms]![DW_Form]![Street] & "*"
    ) 
OR 
    ([Forms]![DW_Form]![Block] Is Null)
)
```

The above queries search the smaller tables. However, when including these in the main query (between the `FROM` and current `WHERE` clauses, with the current `WHERE` replaced with `AND`)I have encountered a truly staggering loss of performance; including just the Street clause (with relevant section of the original query removed) raises processing time from ~5s to ~45s. Adding both subqueries slows the search time to well over three minutes.

At this point it's clear that I'm likely going about this the wrong way; what information I've been able to find (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900762/big-performance-loss-when-using-insubquery-why)) seems to indicate that the subqueries might be running on the entire subtable for every record. What *should* I be doing in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a join instead of a subquery, it generally performs better.
Example:

```
SELECT ...
FROM [Map index] LEFT OUTER JOIN [fileID-Street] 
ON [Map index].fileID=[fileID-Street].fileID
WHERE ... AND [fileID-Street].Street_2 LIKE '*" & [Forms]![DW_Form]![Street] & "*'
```

Comment: This seems to have done the trick, at least in terms of speed; is there any particular reason you used a `left outer join` in your example, or was that selected arbitrarily?

Comment: ...actually, this is giving me completely incorrect results. I'm attempting to filter such that only columns with a fileID that appears in the secondary table are in the result. Using the `JOIN [fileID-Street] AS fis ON [Map index].fileID = fis.fileID` technique results in MORE items in the output.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Try changing `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`. You can also move the `[fileID-Street].Street_2 LIKE '*" & [Forms]![DW_Form]![Street] & "*'` to the ON clause. EG: `FROM [Map index] INNER JOIN [fileID-Street] 
ON [Map index].fileID=[fileID-Street].fileID AND [fileID-Street].Street_2 LIKE '*" & [Forms]![DW_Form]![Street] & "*'`

Comment: My concern is that these joins are producing a large number of records with the same `fileID`, since it's a one-to-many relationship. I might only have six or so for a given search, but that balloons up over a hundred excess records if I add a second join. Is there any way to combat this? Adding a DISTINCT clause seems to be removing some records that actually _are_ distinct, at least if the Find Duplicates query I ran on the non-distinct results is to be believed. (It shows ~200 duplicates on the non-distinct results. DISTINCT removes ~4000 results.)

Comment: See the tables in [this paste](http://pastebin.com/EvYhRe53) for a better explanation of what I'm looking to accomplish.

Comment: Given your paste example,
`SELECT a.fileID FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.fileID=b.fileID AND b.row1 LIKE '*searchterm*' GROUP BY a.fileID`

This will show only one row per fileid matching the searchterm

Comment: I ended up using the technique [here](http://forums.devshed.com/ms-sql-development/807373-select-distinct-post2629865.html#post2629865), which is similar, but takes MIN(secondary-table PK). Used a left join and put the LIKE in my WHERE block to make it extensible to multiple secondary tables.