# Access 2007: Replicating subquery result with joins

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am attempting to design a query that will return a set of rows from table `A` which have a `fileID` value matching at least one row in a subset of table `B`, where table `B` is filtered such that `B.row1 CONTAINS varInput`. (`B` has only two columns, `fileID` and `row1`.)

I have made two attempts at this so far: First with a subquery of the form

```
WHERE 
(
    A.fileID IN 
    (
      SELECT fileID FROM B
      WHERE B.row1 LIKE "*" & varInput & "*"
    ) 
    OR (varInput Is Null)
)
```

While the above method returns the values I'm looking for, it is unacceptably slow; adding it to my WHERE clause results in the search as a whole taking upwards of 45 seconds. (Without the subquery, the search takes less than 3 seconds.)

In an effort to improve speeds, I replaced the subquery with a JOIN operation, as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816055/access-2007-subqueries-causing-massive-performance-loss). However, the join (I'm using `LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.fileID = B.fileID`) does not actually filter out any results, and I'm not sure what I can do to change that, if anything. (Using an inner join instead makes no difference, as every row in `B` contains a `fileID` that is also present in `A`, as `B` is derived from `A`.)

I attempted to improve results by joining on `varInput = B.fileID` instead, but it appears that I cannot use input values (varInput is here the content of a textbox control on an unbound form) in JOIN statements.

For context, `B` is generated as an attempt to normalize `A`, which contains twelve fields for the same category of data. (In this case, street names.) The original query displays most columns of `A`, but only one from the group that have been condensed into `B`. The above subquery gave the same results as the following excerpt from the original query:

```
AND (
  (A.row LIKE "*" & varInput & "*")
  OR (A.row1 LIKE "*" & varInput & "*")
  ...
  OR (A.row12 LIKE "*" & varInput & "*")
)
```

I suppose, then, that my question boils down to "How can the results of the above subquery be replicated in a faster manner?"

Alternately, I believe that the slowdown may have been caused by the subquery executing for each record in table A; if this is the case, what (if anything) can be done to ensure that it runs only once, storing the results so that they can be compared to each record in `A`?

---

I have followed the advice of Gordon Linoff, below, and found that while his method (placing a query *in* a join) is both functional and fast for a single join when `varInput` is given, it does not function as desired when multiple joins are in play, returning rows for which *either* join is true, rather than both. I suspect I can fix this by nesting the joins instead of running them in sequence, but am not certain of the specifics.

To clarify the "multiple joins" aspect, consider a third table `C`. In addition to searching for the `fileID` of rows containing `varInput` in `B`, I also need a row in `C` matching `input2`. (`C` contains columns called `fileID` and `rowC`.) I need to return exactly one record for each `fileID` E such that there is some row in `B` with (`fileID`=E AND `row1`=`varInput`) and there is some row in `C` with (`fileID`=E AND `rowC`=`input2`).

See [this paste](http://pastebin.com/BegMeiLU) for an example. (Linked externally for monospace text.)

Comment: What is `B.row1`?  You said B has only 2 columns, and `row1` is not one of them.  But if `B.row1` is a third field, please explain the logic of `WHERE B.row1 LIKE "*" & B.varInput & "*"`

Comment: Doh! The second column of `B` is indeed `row1` rather than `varInput`. I will edit the question to correct this.

Comment: Please tell us more about `varInput` then.  As best I can tell, that is a VBA variable.   But a query will not recognize a VBA variable.  I don't understand what you're doing.

Comment: `varInput` is the value of a textbox on the form from which we call the query. (`[Forms]![DW_Form]![Street]`, in this case, where `Street` is the name of the textbox control.)

Comment: So then you grab the value of `[Forms]![DW_Form]![Street]`, store it in a variable named `varInput`, and then use that variable when you create the text for a `SELECT` statement.  Do I have that correct now?

Comment: `varInput` is mostly used here to make the question slightly more generic; I'm not actually storing the value, my query references the control directly each time I need the contents. (I recognize that this likely isn't the best method.) I believe you have the general idea, though; the method given in Gordon Linoff's answer below does almost exactly what I'm looking for, but seems to fail when extended to multiple subtables.

Comment: I've edited the question to add a clarification of what I'm looking for; the tables shown in the link at the bottom should hopefully make it fairly clear.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this version?

> I am attempting to design a query that will return a set of rows from
>   table A which have a fileID value matching at least one row in a
>   subset of table B, where table B is filtered such that B.row1 CONTAINS
>   varInput. (B has only two columns, fileID and varInput.)
>
> I have made two attempts at this so far: First with a subquery of the
>   form

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A INNER JOIN
     (SELECT fileID
      FROM B
      WHERE B.row1 LIKE "*" & varInput & "*"
     ) as B
     ON B.fileID = A.fileId
UNION ALL
SELECT A.*
FROM A
WHERE varInput Is Null;
```

This gets rid of the `LEFT JOIN`, using `UNION ALL` for all the data if the input variable is `NULL`.

Also, the subquery might need `SELECT DISTINCT` if the file ids can be duplicated.

Comment: I may not have been detailed enough in my question; there are multiple inputs on the form, not all of which will be linked to subtables like this. As such, I cannot simply `UNION` when the input is `Null`, as there are a notable number of combinations of Null/Not-Null inputs. (Four inputs will be linked to subtables, fourteen will not.) The solution you've provided does seem to work correctly when `varInput` is non-null, but I'm not sure how to deal with the null cases given the variety of possible combinations.

Also, how would I reference B.row1 for further comparisons?

Comment: [This post](http://forums.devshed.com/ms-sql-development/807373-select-distinct-post2629865.html#post2629865) seems to have provided a working solution, though I used LEFT instead of INNER. The gist of it is to join on the PK from the main table, then add MIN(secondary-PK) to your SELECT statement. Group by everything you aren't taking the minimum of. This method seems to be extensible to multiple secondary tables, though I'm not sure of its performance implications in larger databases.